# Outlook Add-in: Does Outlook Horizontal Add-in View Exist?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I’m a developer working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook. We are running into a UI bug with certain window sizes. We are having problems resolving this, because we are supporting a horizontal add-in view that we encountered on Outlook on the web in 2016 (please see links below for examples). We haven’t been able to find this view/layout anywhere over many Outlook platforms. Is it safe for us to assume that the horizontal read view has been completely replaced by the add-in commands version that opens the taskpane on the side?

[Example One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2IT.png)

[Example Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu0lr.png)

Comment: The "gray bar" / "horizontal" taskpane is no longer actively supported. It is recommended to use the add-in commands for a taskpane, or Detected Entities for contextual add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

@K. Yu, horizontal add-ins are no longer supported, so use [Add-In commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook) or [Contextual Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins), depending on what suits your needs.
Check out this [blogpost](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/make-your-add-ins-available-in-the-office-ribbon/) with more information.